# How do you set the height of a div through jQuery using a mix of numbers and other div heights?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get Div1's height set to auto. Then, I want Div2 to be 50 pixels longer than Div1 at all times.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
if(h > 600 ) { 
           $('#Div1').css('height','auto'); 
           $('#Div2').height( $('#Div1').height() + 50 );             
        }
```

This works perfectly fine without the "+ 50" part. With the "+ 50", the page will run, but the code has no effect.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Where is the `h` variables?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and paste it here? @Neo

Comment: @Neo check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6617o4gd/

Comment: Thank you! I can see the error now in my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if(h > 600 ) { 
           $('#Div1').css('height','auto'); 
           $('#Div2').height( parseInt($('#Div1').height() + 50) );             
        }
```

use

> > ParseInt ($('#Div1').height() + 50)

because JavaScript default plus work as  1+1 = 11

i hope this will work 
Please reply me if this will work